# Does $(A) \Rightarrow (B) \Rightarrow (C) \Rightarrow (A)$ mean that $(A), (B), (C)$ are equivalent?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-writing

In complex analysis, let's consider $f(z) \in C^0(D, \mathbb{C})$ and the 3 following affirmations:

$(A) \;\;\;$ *The primitive $F(z)$ of $f(z)$ exists on D* ;

$(B)\;\;\;$ $\displaystyle {\int_{z_1}^{z_2} f = F|_{z_1}^{z_2} = F(z_2) - F(z_1)}$ ;

$(C)\;\;\;$ $\displaystyle \oint _C f = 0 \ \ \forall C $ *admissible simple closed in* $D$.

My book claims that if one of these 3 affirmations is true, the others also are, so $(A) \Leftrightarrow (B) \Leftrightarrow (C)$. Yet, that same book only proves $(A) \Rightarrow (B)$, then $(B) \Rightarrow (C)$ and finally $(C) \Rightarrow (A)$.

That's why I wonder wether $(A) \Rightarrow (B) \Rightarrow (C) \Rightarrow (A)$ mean that $(A), (B), (C)$ are equivalent or not.

Thank you in advance for your comments and answers !

Comment: Yes. See e.g. [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism)

Comment: Unless I misread something, this article shows that $(A) \Rightarrow (C)$ et $(A) \Rightarrow (A)$ (trivial) in my example, but what about the other direction of the implications ?

Comment: This is a standard technique used by many authors. And it works for any given number of statements. However I find it a bit indirect. You should verify that all the desired implications can be proved using the cyclic chain of implications.

Comment: Comment not clear... ASSUMING that the author proves "(A)⇒(B) , then (B)⇒(C) and finally (C)⇒(A)" from first and second we have (A)⇒(C) that with third gives equivalence of A and C. Third and first gives (C)⇒(B) , that in turn with second gives equivalence of B and C. That's all...

Comment: Here is a visual. Suppose you have $n$ points on circle and you can only move from one point to next in clockwise direction (counter clockwise not allowed) in one step. Then one can move from any point to any other point in a finite number of steps.

Comment: Understood, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is simple logic:

$1.\; A\implies B\\
2.\;B\implies C\\
3.\;C\implies A$.

Therefore from line 1. and 3.:
$C\implies B$
hence $C\iff B$

now from lines 1. and 2. $A\implies C$.

and from this and line 3:
$A\iff C$

similarly since $C\iff B$ then $A\iff B$.

so the equivalence is a truth of logic.

we rely on no previous premises of a theory.

Comment: @OP just to make a parallel with ordering relations $A\le B\le C\le A$ means $A=B=C$, and you would prove it the same way.